# mysql query using like invalid

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-5.7

I am using mysql 5.7 and when I use the like query below, I can get the results.
[image]

but if I change the like query as below, I get no results, can anyone tell me what's the problem?
[image]

Comment: What you are trying to do is to use regex in Sql query. You need to look for proper syntax for it if at all mysql supports regex.

Comment: What exact pattern are you trying to match?

Comment: I change the like to rlike, then the problem solved. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `REGEXP` operator if you want to match the pattern, e.g.:

```
SELECT followedCourseIds FROM axn_server.user_wechat WHERE followedCourseIds REGEXP <pattern>;
```

[Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) is the documentation and examples.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
    column RLIKE 'regex'
```

instead of

```
    column LIKE 'regex'
```

The wildcard syntax for ordinary `LIKE` expressions is simpler than regex.